# Using DatePart to show specific Days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to use the DatePart function to show a Week running from Sat - Fri as opposed to your typical Monday - Sunday week?  I know this will return Monday - Sunday, but can ya change it to Sat - Wed?

```
DATEPART(WEEK,[HireDate]) AS Week_Number
```

Comment: What does that even mean? Does Thursday begin the next "week" or does the following Saturday?

Comment: Apalogies.  I would want Week 1 to run From Saturday to Friday (Jan 11 - Jan 17) then Week 2 begin Jan 18 and run 'til Jan 24th.  Does that help clarify?

Comment: Well, you have 3 correct answers already, so I think it's clear enough

Comment: Gotcha, the original post said Sat - Wed, hence my confusion. Looks like you've got some good answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes use [SET DATEFIRST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) this sets the day to count as the first day of the week so it changes on the day you specify.

Comment: AH, I have never used this feature.  Thank you! SET DATEFIRST 3

Comment: @user2954053L Why 3? If you want Saturday to be the first day, it should be 6.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the first day of the week:

```
SET DATEFIRST { number | @number_var }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the first day of week with datefirst.

```
set datefirst 6
```

Datepart week and weekday will work according.
Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx for more details.

Comment: Right, I corrected it. Somehow sticked with Wednesday. Which is 3, I don't know why I wrote 4. :-)